# Hooking x86 reset vector

Tags: assembly, x86

Is it possible to hook the x86 CPU reset vector? (386+, since on the lower ones it's trivial) If so, how could it be done? If not, why does Linux (I've seen a distro) in text mode, in the same terminal as the syslog, show quite a lot of text right in the moment I push the reset button?

I would like to hook that in my future OS, if possible... (like making RESET trigger something similar to Windows' BSOD and dump memory before actually resetting, something something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reset vector for any x86 CPU is the same; it's always 16-bit real mode at either `FFFF:0000` or `F000:FFF0` (both refer to the same physical address), which is almost always a ROM address.

Also, the reset button you mention is a hardware reset, i.e. there's nothing you can do in software to prevent it. It's possible it triggers some sort of ACPI or interrupt event just before resetting the hardware, just to give the OS a brief moment to do something (whether it's flush critical data to disk or otherwise).

Comment: Ah, it could have been a NMI before the actual reset... Thanks!

Comment: You say that "FFFF:FFF0, which is almost always a ROM address."   Why is it though that in this UEFI/PI implementation,  code in the reset vector is there it seems  https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/UefiCpuPkg/ResetVector/Vtf0/Ia16/ResetVectorVtf0.asm#L52   and as I understand it, that UEFI/PI image is flashed (to flash memory) rather than ROM

Comment: @barlop flash memory is a type of ROM, since a simple CPU write instruction can't change its contents

Comment: @DrewMcGowen good point , I notice flash is EEPROM https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69234/what-is-the-difference-between-flash-memory-and-eeprom

Comment: I'm pretty sure in real mode it's `FFFF:0000`; I know for a fact that jumping there is equivalent to resetting. `FFFF:FFF0` is `0x10FFEF`, which is near the end of the [high memory area (HMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory_area), and the HMA is almost if not always RAM.

Comment: @flarn2006 dang, never noticed that - nice catch!

Answer (score 4):

You can't hook the reset vector directly. It's hardwired into the CPU to start executing instructions at address `0xFFFFFFF0`. What you can do is take advantage of an old trick implemented on 80286 BIOSes to allow the CPU to return from protected mode.

The 80286 was the first CPU to implement protected mode and Intel's designers decided that once the CPU switched from real mode to protected mode there was no reason to switch back. The only way a 80286 could get back to real mode once it enabled protected mode is by a reset.

IBM however wanted to make the additional memory that 80286 supported above the 1M real mode addressing limit available to real mode programs. To do this they implemented two features, the first was that the keyboard controller could be instructed to reset the CPU. The second was that after reset the BIOS would look for a special pattern in memory. If it found it then it would skip its normal initialization and boot tasks and jump to an address given in memory. By combining these two features the BIOS was able to provide real mode services that used protected mode to accesss memory above 1M.

Later BIOS implementations better ways to perform these tasks. For example a faster way to reset the processor was to cause a triple fault, and the undocumented `LOADALL` instruction could be used to access memory above 1M without switching to protected mode. The '386 removed the need for any trickery, Intel realized their mistake and allowed the processor to be switched from protected mode to real mode without a reset.

However modern BIOS implementations still support skipping initialization if a special pattern exists in memory after reset as many applications made use of it. Notably Windows on 80286 CPUs used it to allow it to support running MS-DOS applications. Maybe your Linux machine is using this feature, but it's also possible that your reset button isn't actually a reset button on your machine.

If you want to take advantage of this feature in your own code then put the real mode address you want to the BIOS to call after reset in `0040h:0067h`, store the 16-bit magic number `4321h` in `0040h:0072h` and then reset the processor. Apparently asking the keyboard controller to do the reset doesn't work reliably on modern systems. It also won't work with the the reset button if it resets more than just the CPU and causes memory to be erased as well.

Comment: Well, on reset my BIOS redoes the memory test (and the "beep"). On Windows' reboot it doesn't. On Linux reboot/reset it does. Maybe it's that NMI the other user (indirectly) mentioned? Anyway you have answered a different question, useful in its own right, but not my question.

Comment: I've answered the question you posted. This is as close as you can come to hooking the x86 reset vector. If that's not what you want to do you should edit your question to reflect that. If you all you want to do is skip the memory test on reboot you can write 1234h to 0040h:0072h. The what Linux will do if you ask it to do a "warm reboot", and presumably what Windows does.

Comment: I have added an edit so that the answer also answers what I wanted to know. After the edit (last paragraph) I marked your reply as answer.

Comment: And yes, it's a true reset button.

Comment: A true reset button wouldn't send an NMI and then reset the processor. Not that you have anything beyond speculation that's what happening when you press the reset button on your PC. Your edit was inappropriate and rejected by the reviewers before I had to chance to reject or revert it myself. If you think your edit was the correct answer you should unaccept my answer and post the edit as its own answer. However I wouldn't recommend acceping your answer until you've actually written the code in your future OS that proves your speculation is correct.

Comment: I'm having a standard late-2006 PC (Windows Vista Certified label on the motherboard box). The only changes since are a BIOS update (the latest version, May 2007), extra RAM and an older Intel Pentium 4 CPU. The behaviour occured in the old configuration. Also that screen is quite brief (If I can capture it by video, I will get a link). I have unaccepted all answers. Also, the question is about the real hardware (this certainly doesn't happen in virtual machines, I think, but I will also check)